# Converting PDF to CSV using Python 3.7 Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to convert a pdf file "January2019" into a csv file. The original pdf only contains tables on certain pages and I'm trying to extract those tables. I'm following the tutorial on http://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Using_Python_to_Extract_Tables_From_PDFs.php but when I inserted:

import PyPDF2

PDFfilename = "January2019.pdf"

pfr = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(January2019, "rb"))

the output shows as ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'...

PS. I'm very new to Python and coding. Any tips will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

have you installed PyPDF2 yet? If not, run this in your terminal (or cmd or powershell)

```
conda install -c conda-forge pypdf2
```

see the [docs on Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pypdf2)

Comment: this is what I got in return..

File "<ipython-input-43-bbdc5a9766e7>", line 1
    conda install -c conda-forge pypdf2
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I got a response saying 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file...I know im missing something very basic...

Comment: so, Conda is the built-in package manager for Anaconda. Do you have Anaconda installed? typically, the path to that program will be added to the system path by the installer, meaning that you can call it the way I posted in the termina). However, if for whatever reason it is not, you should be able to find it (on windows) at `C:/Anaconda/Library/bin` (you can add this to your user environment variables to make things easier. I promise there's a question on SO that answers how to do that.)

Comment: Okay, I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

The error shows that you do not have `PYPDF2` installed.

follow this procedure to install it.

If you are using Anaconda:

- Go to your Anaconda prompt and enter this code
  `conda config --add channels conda-forge` press 'Enter' key
- Once the conda forge channel has been opened, put this code
  `conda install pypdf2` and press the 'Enter' key

Answer (score 0):

First install the PyPDF2 module using pip.
Run this command in terminal/prompt:

```
pip install pypdf2
```

Comment: He mentioned that he's using Anaconda, so he should probably use the conda package manager, rather than the python package manager.

Comment: pip install pypdf2 also gave me 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Your pip is probably not in PATH. Try the answer posted by David Culbreth

Comment: @SangwooChun, I recommend you take to the hunt on SO to figure out how to set up your dev environment for python. these errors have been solved in other problems on SO.

Answer (score 0):

What this error is telling you is correct. You haven't installed the module PyPDF2.
Install first with:

`pip install pypdf2`

Comment: He mentioned that he's using Anaconda, so he should probably use the conda package manager, rather than the python package manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't manage to install PyPDF2 successfully, the other option ("Writing the Table Data to a CSV With PDFTables") doesn't require you to install this package. You will just be calling PDFTables via an API which is a little simpler.